# exporting crystal report to PDF causes loss in data

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

My report is displayed in a aspx file using Crystal Report Viewer, After I click on the button to export the report to PDF all data is lost and only the graphic is remained in the page. what can be the problem ?

can you help plz

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all actions you click on the CrystalReportViewer trigger a postback. Most of the time, people are not storing the reportdocument in session then re-assigning it to the viewer. In this answer I demonstrate how to move your existing code into a model that stores the reportdocument to prevent problems when export/print/paging/etc.

[crystal report toolbar button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191525/crystal-report-toolbar-button-not-working/10202603#10202603)

Answer (score 0):

For my web project, I assigned Session Data into ReportSource at Page_Init() method in aspx file. Because the report data are transferred from another page by Session data.

```
void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.rptViewer.ReportSource = Session["ReportData"];
}
```

Also, do the same in Page_Load method of "aspx.cs" file as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {


        rptViewer.Visible = true;
        this.rptViewer.ReportSource = Session["ReportData"];
        this.rptViewer.ShowFirstPage();

    }


}
```

After that, problem solved.